# Using 2 passports Canadian/UK when visiting the UK

Tags: passports

I will be visiting Scotland and wondered if I can use my UK passport to enter so I can use the shorter line at immigration, then use my Canadian passport when I return to Canada?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's not just a matter of shorter lines, in many countries you have to enter using the passport of country X if you're a citizen of country X.